# Can tangent vectors be thought of in terms of asymptotically close points?

Tags: differential-geometry

I understand the usual definition of a tangent vector in terms of differential operators.

However, suppose I have three points on a Riemannian manifold, one with coordinates $\theta$, one with coordinates $\theta+\varepsilon\delta_1\theta$ and one with coordinates $\theta+\varepsilon\delta_2 \theta$. In the limit of small $\varepsilon$, it seems reasonable to think of
$$
\sum_{ij}g_{ij}(\theta)\delta_1\theta^i\delta_2\theta^j
$$
as a scalar product between the "vectors" $\delta_1\theta$ and $\delta_2\theta$.

Is this a sensible way to think about scalar products and tangent vectors on a Riemannian manifold? If not, what's wrong with it? Or if so, is the expression I've written down correct, and how can it be related to the usual definition of a tangent vector in terms of differential operators?

Comment: Do you know the definition of tangent vectors as equivalence classes of curves? It's closer to this intuition: the class of curves with coordinates $\epsilon \mapsto \theta + \epsilon \,\delta \theta + o(\epsilon)$ is the vector with components $\delta \theta.$

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis my colleague just mentioned that definition to me also, but it's not one I was previously familiar with. I will look into it.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis if you know a good resource for that, it would be really helpful.